# Uniforms (uniforms.tools) - Prevent users from selecting the same option in two SelectField (React)

Tags: reactjs, validation, schema

I have a schema like this to be used in a [Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUEHg.png) (using uniforms.tools) in the attached link where Current Office and Destination Office use the same list of options.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "title": "Change Office Request",
  "required": ["currentOffice", "destinationOffice", "dueDate", "content"],
  "properties": {
    "currentOffice": {
      "type": "string",
      "uniforms": {
        "index": 1,
        "resource": 7,
        "uiComponent": "SelectResourceField"
      }
    },
    "destinationOffice": {
      "type": "string",
      "uniforms": {
        "index": 2,
        "resource": 7,
        "uiComponent": "SelectResourceField"
      }
    },
    "dueDate": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date",
      "uniforms": {
        "index": 3
      }
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "string",
      "uniforms": {
        "index": 4,
        "uiComponent": "QuillEditorField"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that users can submit the form when **selecting the same option in those two select inputs**. I am thinking about two ways to solve this problem:

- Solution 1: Show a validation message showing users that they cannot select the same option for both fields.
- Solution 2: When users select an option in the first select field, that option gets filtered out in the second select field so that they cannot select the same option.

I haven't found the way to implement either one of these two solutions. I would really appreciate if you guys could help me with this.